# what is replacement of StandardTokenizerInterface in solr 5.3.1

Tags: java, solr, lucene, stringtokenizer

in lucene 4.3.1 there was an interface StandardTokenizerInterface and a number of classes implement this class, such as StandardTokenizerImpl and ..... this interface doesn't exist in solr 5.3.1... what is the replacement of this class in solr 5.3.1?

Comment: Looks like the interface has been removed, but the implementations class are available in the `lucene-analyzers-common` jar. I checked 5.2.1 version. [Link](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.lucene/lucene-analyzers-common/5.2.1/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizerImpl.java#StandardTokenizerImpl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interface was not replaced, it was removed entirely, as it was deemed to no longer serve a useful purpose, due to the changes in how backwards compatibility is handled (instead of passing in a version arg, you would just use [StandardTokenizer40](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/std40/StandardTokenizer40.html), for instance).  Ticket here: [LUCENE-6000](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-6000)

The calls specified in the interface are still used in pretty much the same way by the current [StandardAnalyzerImpl](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_1/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardTokenizerImpl.html) though, as far as I can tell.